# uicollectionview with custom layout and multiple headers

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I have a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewLayout and want to add multiple headers per section to display the different hours of a day. Something similar to a week view that has the hours on the left side vertically but on the top and horizontally for my case.

The cells display well but the content is weird, it looks like the cells are reused and only 1 of the 5 that are on screen have a content. Other 4 headers have only background color with no content into.

When i scroll, there is some glitch and update only one cell (sometimes 2) at one time and the content can be switched or misplaced by one row.

Here is the code i use in controller, viewDidLoad

```
[self.epgCollectionView registerClass:[HeaderTimeReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:EpgKindTimeRowHeader withReuseIdentifier:HeaderTimeReuseIdentifier];
```

same controller more below:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionReusableView *view;
if (kind == EpgKindTimeRowHeader){
   HeaderTimeReusableView *timeRowHeader = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:HeaderTimeReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    timeRowHeader.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%lir%li", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    view = timeRowHeader;

}
return view;
```

}

I suppose my custom UICollectionViewLayout good since i can see the multiple header on the place i want.

My question are:

1. Is it possible to have multiple headers per section ?
2. How to avoid the reuse / recycle effect for these headers ?
3. The UICollectionViewCells use the dequeue too but we can have multiple cells per section, so why does it not work for headers/UICollectionReusableView ?

Answer (score 0):

As always, it's when i post a question that i find the answer...

This is the good code for my reusable view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSLog(@"HeaderTimeReusableView.h initWithFrame");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60*3, 30)];
    self.title.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    self.title.text = @"3";
    [self addSubview:self.title];

}
return self;
```

}

I had previoulsy allocated the label frame like this:

```
self.title.frame = frame;
```

And for some reason, the frame value is not what i have expected. With the hard coded one, it's working fine.